# Fazer um foreach dentro de uma cshtml(view) vindo de uma controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Fiz um código usando *Linq* e *jQuery*. Acontece que está me dando um problema que não consigo resolver, que é criar um *Treeview* dinamicamente. Então tive outra idéia. Fazer o `foreach` direto na *View* (cshtml). Aí vem a pergunta, como eu faço um `foreach` dentro da *View* e em cima de um resultado de uma *Linq* que está em minha controller?

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ArvoreAcao(string _uf)
{
    RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();
    var monta_arvore = (from rup in db.Ruptura
      from apr in db.Apresentacao
          .Where(apr => apr.Codigo_Apresentacao == rup.Codigo_Apresentacao)
      from pdv in db.PDV.Where(pdv => pdv.CodigoPDV == rup.CodigoPDV)
      from mot in db.Motivo.Where(mot => mot.IDMotivo == rup.IDMotivo)
          select new {
              rup.IDRuptura,
              rup.DataRuptura,
              rup.IDMotivo,
              mot.Motivo1,
              rup.IDOrigem,
              rup.CodigoPDV,
              pdv.UF,
              pdv.Cidade,
              loja = pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao,
              rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
              apr.Unidade_Negocio,
              apr.Franquia,
              apr.Familia,
              apr.Descricao
          }).ToList().Distinct().OrderBy(apr => apr.Descricao);

    return Json(new { monta_arvore }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

E essa seria a *View* onde o `foreach` acontecerá. O `foreach` estaria dentro da *div* *jqxTree*, ou seja, apagaria todo o conteúdo estático de lá (fake) e faria ele de forma dinâmica.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Acao";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/Jqwidgets/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h2>Tomada de Ação</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxCodTipo">UF:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxCodTipo" id="cbxCodTipo" 
                onchange=" return MontaCidades();">
                <option value="00">Selecione um estado</option>
                <option value="AC">ACRE</option>
                <option value="AL">ALAGOAS</option>
                <option value="AP">AMAPÁ</option>
                <option value="AM">AMAZONAS</option>
                <option value="BA">BAHIA</option>
                <option value="CE">CEARÁ</option>
                <option value="DF">DISTRITO FEDERAL</option>
                <option value="ES">ESPÍRITO SANTO</option>
                <option value="GO">GOIÁS</option>
                <option value="MA">MARANHÃO</option>
                <option value="MT">MATO GROSSO</option>
                <option value="MS">MATO GROSSO DO SUL</option>
                <option value="MG">MINAS GERAIS</option>
                <option value="PA">PARÁ</option>
                <option value="PB">PARAÍBA</option>
                <option value="PR">PARANÁ</option>
                <option value="PE">PERNAMBUCO</option>
                <option value="PI">PIAUÍ</option>
                <option value="RJ">RIO DE JANEIRO</option>
                <option value="RN">RIO GRANDE DO NORTE</option>
                <option value="RS">RIO GRANDE DO SUL</option>
                <option value="RO">RONDÔNIA</option>
                <option value="RR">RORAIMA</option>
                <option value="SC">SANTA CATARINA</option>
                <option value="SP">SÃO PAULO</option>
                <option value="SE">SERGIPE</option>
                <option value="TO">TOCANTINS</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="cbxCidade">Cidade:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="cbxCidade" id="cbxCidade">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxRede">Rede:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxRede" id="cbxRede"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="cbxRede">Descrição:</label>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control col-md-4" name="cbxDescricao" id="cbxDescricao">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxProduto">Produto:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxProduto" id="cbxProduto">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <label for="cbxUnNegocio">Unidade Negócio:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control col-md-6" name="cbxUnNegocio" id="cbxUnNegocio">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="content">
    <div class="listTree"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" return MontaArvore();">Pesquisar</button>
</div>

<br>

<div id='jqxWidget'>
    <div style='float: left; width:auto;'>
        <div id='jqxTree' style='visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 20px;'>
            <ul>
                <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                    Produto
                    <ul>
                        <li item-expanded='true'>
                            MIP
                            <ul>
                                <li item-expanded='true'>
                                    Família: ACCUVIT
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>ACCUVIT COMREV FRX30</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li item-expanded='true'>
                                    Família: FLOGORAL
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>FLOGORAL SPRAY CEREJA CTX30ML</li>
                                        <li>FLOGORAL SPRAY MENTA CTX30ML</li>
                                        <li>FLOGORAL CREM DENTAL CTX70G</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div style='margin-left: 60px; float: left;'>
            <div style='margin-top: 10px;'>
                <input id='jqxCheckBox' type="hidden">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>@*Fim da div jqxWidget *@

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="txtObs">Observação:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <textarea id="txtObs" style="width: 450px;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="content">
    <div class="listTree"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ">Gravar</button>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index", "Home", new {}, new {@class = "btn btn-danger"})
</div>

@*<script class="cssdeck" 
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>*@
<script class="cssdeck" 
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>    
<script src="~/Scripts/Acao/Acao.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxtree.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
```

**Importante**: A controller se Chama `AcaoController`. O *.edmx* está dentro de Model (Folder) e uso *Entity*.

**Fiz isso na controller**:

```
ViewBag.result_arvore = monta_arvore;
```

**E depois isso na *View***.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.result_arvore)
{
    <ul>
        <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
            @item.Motivo1
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

O resultado é esse:

[image: mensagem de erro]

**Como eu faço um `foreach`, mas em cima do resultado de uma linq que vem da controller?**

Fiz alterações e me dá o erro que não é possível fazer o `foreach`, porque a minha classe não tem uma propriedade pública GetEnumerator. Como eu faço?

Ficou assim agora:
Minha View apenas a parte do `foreach`. Os demais são os mesmo acima.

```
<div id='jqxWidget'>
    <div style='float: left; width:auto;'>
        <div id='jqxTree' style='visibility: hidden; float: left; margin-left: 20px;'>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <ul>
                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                        @item.Motivo
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </div>

        <div style='margin-left: 60px; float: left;'>
            <div style='margin-top: 10px;'>
                <input id='jqxCheckBox' type="hidden">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**O código em minha controller**:

```
public ActionResult Acao()
{
    RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

    var monta_arvore =   db.Ruptura.Select(rup=> new MontaArvoreAcao {
        IDRuptura = rup.IDRuptura,
        DataRuptura = rup.DataRuptura,
        IDMotivo = rup.IDMotivo,
        Motivo = rup.Motivo.Motivo1,
        IDOrigem = rup.IDOrigem,
        CodigoPDV = rup.CodigoPDV,
        UF  = rup.PDV.UF,
        Cidade = rup.PDV.Cidade,
        CnpjDescricao= rup.PDV.Cnpj + " - " + rup.PDV.Descricao,
        Codigo_Apresentacao = rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
        Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Unidade_Negocio,
        Franquia = rup.Apresentacao.Franquia,
        Familia  = rup.Apresentacao.Familia,
        Descricao = rup.Apresentacao.Descricao
    }).ToList();

    return View(monta_arvore);
}
```

**Minha Model**:

```
public class MontaArvoreAcao
{
    public int IDRuptura { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataRuptura { get; set; }
    public int IDMotivo { get; set; }
    public string Motivo { get; set; }
    public int IDOrigem { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPDV { get; set; }
    public string UF { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string CnpjDescricao { get; set; }
    public string Codigo_Apresentacao { get; set; }
    public string Unidade_Negocio { get; set; }
    public string Franquia { get; set; }
    public string Familia { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}

public class MontaArvoreAcaoDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MontaArvoreAcao> montaArvoreAcao { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas reforçando, você pode passar o objeto de duas formas para a `view`

```
public ActionResult minhaAcao
{
    List<ObjetoModel> objeto = (from u in objetos select u).toList();
    return View(objeto);
}
```

A sua `View` ficaria desta forma

```
@model IENumerable<ObjetoModel>

@foreach(var objeto in Model)
{
   @objeto.propriedade <br />
}
```

E a outra forma é através da utilização de `ViewBag` que pelo jeito você sabe utilizar.

O Erro que está dando ao seu problema é que muito provavelmente a consulta está retornando nulo. Ainda sim aconselho o uso do retorno do Json da seguinte forma.

```
Return Json(monta_arvore);
```

Utilizo desta forma em meus projetos para consultas em `Json` e sempre obtive sucesso.

E em sua consulta mude para este formato.

```
var monta_arvore = (from rup in db.Ruptura
    from apr in db.Apresentacao.Where(apr => apr.Codigo_Apresentacao == rup.Codigo_Apresentacao)
    from pdv in db.PDV.Where(pdv => pdv.CodigoPDV == rup.CodigoPDV)
    from mot in db.Motivo.Where(mot => mot.IDMotivo == rup.IDMotivo)
        select new {
            rup.IDRuptura,
            rup.DataRuptura,
            rup.IDMotivo,
            mot.Motivo1,
            rup.IDOrigem,
            rup.CodigoPDV,
            pdv.UF,
            pdv.Cidade,
            loja = pdv.Cnpj + " - " + pdv.Descricao,
            rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
            apr.Unidade_Negocio,
            apr.Franquia,
            apr.Familia,
            apr.Descricao
        }).Distinct().OrderBy(apr => apr.Descricao).ToList();
```

Em seu `Foreach` tente fazer da seguinte forma

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>@item.Motivo</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: @pnet Preciso ter certeza de uma coisa, sua consulta está retornando resultado? Se sim verifique no console do navegador se está retornando o JSON e possíveis erros no Jquery. Também coloque aqui seu código Jquery para analise.

Comment: Faça o Foreach da seguinte forma como está na resposta editada. @pnet algumas coisas estão me deixando um tanto quanto com dúvidas, em sua `div` *#jqxTree* há um style setado para `visibility:hidden` isso fará com que sua `div` não apareça, se possível coloque um breakpoint na sua consulta e verifique se está retornando todos os registros, muito provavelmente ele está populando a lista com um objeto. Qual o widget que está utilizando?

Comment: Não, isso não é o problema. Há um javascript que trata isso. Se eu retirar isso, dá uma zica lascada. Conforme você colocou, deu certo, sem problemas, joe. Agora sim, vou montar os demais filhos. Motivo é o pai e agora terei que fazer com Família, Unidade_Negocio e o produto em si, que é o tri-neto da árvore. Conforme seu exemplo, para cada iteração, haverá um <ul> fora, certo?

Comment: Sim, acredito que haverá outros `foreach` dentro de cada `li` obviamente com um `if` (verificando se o pai é pai dele) e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o conteúdo da sua ViewBag está vindo nulo, será preciso fazer uma verificação antes.

Você também precisa dizer qual o tipo da sua ViewBag para realizar a iteração e acessar as propriedades do objeto.

```
@foreach (var item in (List<SeuTipo>)ViewBag.result_arvore)
{
      <ul>
         <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
            @item.Motivo1
         </li>
      </ul>
}
```